# "CAST" function with "DISTINCT ON" not changing the type of the field

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables parent and child . I need to join these two tables and get the results into one.
This pid(one column in parent table) may have duplicate entries and the field type of pid is VARCHAR.
But the field type of 'cid' in the child table is INTEGER.

As i need distinct value i used DISTINCT ON in the patent table query. When i take union with child table,
the query throws error because of FIELD TYPE differs(pid and cid).
I used `"DISTINCT ON" (CAST(pid AS INTEGER))` to make the CAST same for both tables.

But the CAST of pid is not changing. Still its shows error.
When i use `"DISTINCT CAST(pid AS INTEGER))"` instead of `"DISTINCT ON"` no errors came, but the result(number of rows) is not correct.

The query i used

```
Select DISTINCT ON (pid) pid AS id,
first_name
last_name AS last_name,
email AS email
from parent where pid IS NOT NULL

UNION

Select cid  AS id,
child_first_name AS first_name,
child_last_name AS last_name,
child_email AS email
from child where cid IS NOT NULL
```

**Is any one have idea of using "CAST" function with "DISTINCT ON".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `DISTINCT ON (CAST(pid AS INTEGER)) pid AS id`

This will cast the `pid` value for the `DISTINCT` calculation, not for the result.

Assuming you don't need to cast the value in order to do a `DISTINCT` on it, you should do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pid) pid::INTEGER AS id,
...

UNION

SELECT cid,
...
```

i.e., cast it when it's being selected, rather than in the `DISTINCT` calculation. If you do need to cast it in there as well, then you simply have to cast it in both places.